# When I add a new case by using 'insert from existing cases', both cases are linked

Tags: testing, copy, devops

When I add a new case by using 'insert from existing cases', these cases are linked. There is no visible link between both test cases, but if I change one, it changes also the other.

I would like to copy test cases from a test plan to another. I don't want to copy the test plans, I only want to copy the test cases.

Is it something possible ? I am using DEVOPS.

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by "I am using DEVOPS" ?

Comment: This is the version I am using : Azure DevOps Server
Version Dev18.M170.8